# How to quick search libraries for undefined references.

Tags: c, linker, libraries

While linking program using gnu `arm-none-eabi-ld` I got few undefined references for example: `__aeabi_uidiv` and `memcpy` and to find where they reside I used `ar t libc.a` and `ar t libgcc.a`. I have found `memcpy` inside libc.a but I can't find `__aeabi_uidiv`. Listing all libraries is rather inconvenient and time-consuming and I wonder what is the best way to search for .o files in libraries? Should I add to my linker as much libraries as possible and left it the job to find files or is there some magic website that after typing undefined reference will tell me in which lib I can find it ? Btw. anyone knows where I can find `__aeabi_uidiv`?

Answer (score 1):

> While linking program using gnu `arm-none-eabi-ld`

That is your problem right there.

In general, on UNIX, no user-level program should ever be linked using `ld`. You should instead use appropriate compiler driver (e.g. `arm-none-eabi-gcc` for `C` or `arm-none-eabi-g++` for `C++`) to perform the linking.

The compiler driver will *automatically* add libraries to your link which are appropriate for this particular compiler. Here, it is likely that the appropriate libraries are `libgcc` and `libc`.

Comment: So in what cases is ld used ?

Comment: @AlBundy In *special* cases. Such as, linking stand-alone boot loader, or the linux kernel, or bare-metal embedded OS image.